# Why does Metal slow down when the number of fragment shader arguments increases?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, fragment-shader, metalkit

I have a very basic fragment shader that accepts an array of array textures defined like so:

```
fragment float4 shader(RasterizerData in [[ stage_in ]],
                       sampler sampler2d [[ sampler(0) ]],
                       const array<texture2d_array<half>, 5> textures [[ texture(0) ]]) {

  return float4(textures[in.textureIndex].sample(sampler2d, in.textureCoordinate, in.textureSlice));
}
```

I'd like to pass a variable number of textures to this shader. Each texture is an array texture and each array texture is a different size. (Hence why I can't just pass in a single array texture.)

In the code above, I've arbitrarily defined the array size to be `5` because I normally have only 1 texture. If I have less than 5 textures, then the fragment indexes are not set in my application code.

My app code is similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textures.size(); ++i) {
  [renderEncoder setFragmentTexture:textures[i] atIndex:i];
}
```

With an array size of `5`, performance is fine. However, if the only change I make is to redefine the size of the array to `64` in the shader, then overall rendering performance plummets. No other changes are made, which means that most of the fragment texture indexes are not set.

Why does this change impact performance so much?

The GPU debugger shows that most of the time is spent in my render encoder's `drawIndexedPrimitives`. (24.04 ms) When I declare a much smaller array size, then I can easily achieve 60fps.

*On macOS 10.14, MacBook Pro 13" TB 2016.*

Comment: What's is your texture size?

Comment: The array textures have size of 1024x1024, 512x512, 256x256, etc... Sometimes I only need the 1024 array texture, but other times I need the smaller ones. Which is why the number of textures passed in is variable. (This is not related to mipmapping.)

Comment: Is `in.textureIndex` really a varying (can be different for every invocation of the shader)?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying a "wall of tiles". There could be dozens of tiles. Each tile is one of four different sizes called a tile group. Each tile group has an array texture. Each tile's content is generated from a service and sent over in increasingly higher resolution. When a tile passes through the fragment shader, it needs to know which slice in which array texture to sample from. Those two values can constantly change based on what the service has rendered. (Before the render command, there's a blit command that copies from an IOSurface into an "available" array texture's slice.)